# Objective-c runtime thoughts

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Here [Understand Objective-C runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367112/understand-objective-c-runtime) is my question about how objective-c runtime work.
What I still can't understand is does the allocated memory for Person instance contain only isa pointer to class or something else ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does alloc work in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758609/how-does-alloc-work-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great paper if you want to know the layout of Objective-C objects [here](http://algorithm.com.au/downloads/talks/objective-c-internals/objective-c-internals.pdf) (pdf warning), but in short, the memory for every object contains an isa pointer and space for all its iVars, including inherited ones from its superclasses.

Answer (score 2):

The memory allocated for the `Person` instance has room for all of `Person`'s instance variables, and all of the instance variables of all of `Person`'s superclasses.